# Как исправить эту функцию js?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть число Фибоначчи записанное через рекурсию:

```
    function fib(n) {
      return n <= 1 ? n : fib(n - 1) + fib(n - 2);
    }

    alert( fib(3) ); // 2
    alert( fib(7) ); // 13
```

как ее изменить что бы это было замыкание js?

Answer (score 1):

[Алгоритм в другом ответе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/437928/176684) работает нормально, но по-моему, лучще без массива и допольнительной функции, потому что таким образом код проще и быстрее.

```js
function fib(n) {
    var a = 0, b = 1;
    while(n-- > 0) {
        var t = b;
        b += a;
        a = t;
    }
    return a;
}

alert(fib(3)); // 2
alert(fib(7)); // 13
```

Comment: задача стоит функцию замыкания применить

Comment: @zorro Не понял. `while` не замыкание, что ли?

Comment: сорри, согласен, но выдает она числа fib каждый раз после записанния значений в alert вручную

Comment: С `for(var i = 0; i < n; i++)` тоже в принципе можно, я просто выбрал `while` потому что `i` не используется внутри замыкания.

Comment: @zorro Я просто создал итеративную функцию, которая работает так, как рекурсивную функцию в вопросе. Если хотите `nextFibonacci`, можно так: `var nextFibonacci = (function(a,b){ return function() {var t = b; b += a; a = t; return b - a; }; })(0, 1);`

Comment: Нет, while - это не замыкание.

Comment: @Qwertiy Дело в том, что я не очень хорошо владею русский язык. Я думал, что значит loop, но на самом деле, значит closure, да?

Comment: Да, замыкание - это closure.

Answer (score 0):

```
var fibonacci = (function () {
    var arr = [0, 1];

    return function () {
        var num = arr[arr.length - 1],
            len = arr.length;
        arr.push(arr[len - 1] + arr[len - 2]);
        return num;
    };
}());

//test
var i;
for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    console.log(fibonacci());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Думаю, имелось в виду ппревращение функции в function expression, чтобы имя попало в замыкание. В таком случае последующее переприсваивание `fib` не испортит рекурсию.

```js
var fib = function fib(n) {
  return n <= 1 ? n : fib(n - 1) + fib(n - 2);
};

console.log(fib(3), fib(7));

var x = fib;
fib = null; // Evil code

console.log(x(3), x(7));
```

А этот код не сработает:

```js
function fib(n) {
  return n <= 1 ? n : fib(n - 1) + fib(n - 2);
}

console.log(fib(3), fib(7));

var x = fib;
fib = null; // Evil code

console.log(x(3), x(7));
```