# JavaScript: Вывести массив чисел Фибоначчи на экран

Tags: javascript, числа-фибоначчи

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как в *js* cоздать одномерный массив, из *n* элементов,  заполненный  числами последовательности Фибоначчи, и вывести на экран.

Comment: Создать, заполнить, вывести. В чем конкретно вопрос?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как исправить эту функцию js?](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/437927/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%8d%d1%82%d1%83-%d1%84%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8e-js)

Comment: @Darth, я бы не сказал что это дубликат. По ссылке требуется сгенерировать последовательность Фибоначчи с определенными ограничениями налагаемыми на код.

Comment: сложно чтоле дописать var array=[] и array.push(очередное число)?

Comment: @Darth, не сложно, просто это не совсем дубликат :) Хотя это всего лишь мое субъективное мнение.

Comment: Это не дубликат. Там вопрос про защиту рекурсивной функции замыканием, а тут про вычисление с сохранением в массив.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
var n = 10; // Сколько элементов хотим получить
var fibonacci = [0, 1]; // Первые два элемента последовательности Фибоначчи

for (i = 2; i < n; i ++) {
  // Получаем i-й элемент последовательности как сумму предыдущих двух
  fibonacci[i] = fibonacci[i-1] + fibonacci[i-2];
}

console.log(fibonacci.slice(0,n));
// slice отрезает от массива первые n элементов, если n < 2
```

Comment: А чем ваш ответ принципиально отличается от ответа @A1essandro?

Comment: Ваше решение не будет работать для `n = 1`

Comment: Спасибо, поправил решение!

Answer (score 4):

Задаем `n`, который должен быть больше или равен 0, далее:

```
var f = [0, 1]; //Первые значения

if (n <= 2) { //если n <= 2

    var result = f.slice(0, n); //записываем в результат срез f от 0 до n

} else {

    for (i = 0; i < n - 2; i++) { // повторяем n-2 раза, т.к. 2 элемента уже есть
        f.push(f[f.length - 1] + f[f.length - 2]); //заполняем (n+2)-й элемент
    }

    var result = f; //записываем в result наш массив f

}

alert(result); //вывод result на экран (через алерт)
```

`f[f.length - 1]` получает последний элемент массива, `f[f.length - 2]` - предпоследний.

[Array.Push()](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) - метод вставляющий элемент в конец массива.

[Array.Slice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) - метод возвращающий срез массива

[Вот инфа](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) вообще про массивы.

Comment: Что же вы так не любите `;`, `{` и `}`?)

Comment: Извиняюсь, некоторое время кодил на Python'e))

Answer (score 2):

Обернём весь код в ф-ю:

```
function fibi(n) {  // число n передадим параметром в ф-ю
```

Инициализируем переменную, которая будет содержать текущее значение суммы:

```
    var sum = 0
```

счётчик итераций:

```
        ,i
```

текстовая строка для вывода массива:

```
        ,str
```

и сам массив:

```
        ,arr = []
    ;
```

Закрутим цикл, где будем считать итерации, чтобы достигли n:

```
    for( i=0; i<n; i++) {
```

Очередное значение массива получаем прибавлением к «текущей» сумме (еёже потом вставляем в конец массива) предпоследнего на сейчас элемента массива. Особых случая два: когда массив пуст – вставляем 0; и когда в нём единственный элемент, тогда добавляем в хвост единицу.

```
        if( arr.length > 1)  sum += arr[ arr.length-2];
        if( arr.length == 1) sum = 1;
        if( arr.length == 0) sum = 0;
```

Запихиваем это значение в конец массива:

```
        arr.push( sum);
```

Конец цикла – повторить, но не взбалтывать:

```
    }
```

Получить массив как строку для вывода:

```
    str = arr.join(", "); // склеить элементы массива запятой-с-пробелом
```

Вывести в консоль:

```
    console.log(str);
```

Или в документ, раз уж стоит тег "веб-программирование":

```
    document.body.innerHTML = str;
```

Конец кода и ф-ии:

```
}
```

[Проверяем](http://jsfiddle.net/sergiks/3zpsj4r9/):

```
fibi(4); // выводит 0, 1, 1, 2
```

Answer (score 1):

Если совсем лениво, то можно решить так:

```
var fibonacci = new Array(0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89, 144, 233, 377, 610, 987, 1597, 2584, 4181, 6765, 10946); 

alert(fibonacci);
```

а вообще загуглите "javascript массивы" - там все элементарно.

Comment: Хотя в общем случае ваш ответ не является верным, но все равно плюсую за лень :)

Comment: Спасибо, но нам ведь не указано, число n.