# С помощью цикла for с пустым телом сформируйте строку ряда Фибоначчи: 0 1 1 2 3 5 8 13

Tags: javascript, for, числа-фибоначчи

```
let a = 1;
let b = 1;
let c;
let n = 10;
let i;
for (; (i <= n) && (c = a + b) && (a = b) && (b = c); i++) {}
```

Помогите, пожалуйста, совершенно не понимаю, как без тела цикла вообще можно вывести ряд фибоначчи.

Comment: То есть ты не в курсе из чего состоит цикл for? Так может учебник прочитать по основам?

Comment: в курсе - вход, шаг и тело. Вопрос в том, что без тела цикл закроется и только изменит переменную, а как вывести ряд...

Comment: нет не в курсе. есть три позиции в цикле `for (1 ; 2 ; 3)`. Вот что там происходит в цифре 3?

Comment: Хотя номер 2 тоже сойдёт.... надо знать в какой момент выполняется 2 и 3 номера

Comment: Ну собственно ты почти все сделал, осталось только добавить `console.log(c)` в теле цикла, и перед этим вывести первые ва числа. Если же хочешь вывести как одну строку, то используй "аккамулятор" строк (сложение)

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [JavaScript: Вывести массив чисел Фибоначчи на экран](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/450971/javascript-%d0%92%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%b2-%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%b5%d0%bb-%d0%a4%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d1%87%d0%b8-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d1%8d%d0%ba%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd)

Answer (score 5):

```js
let string_fibo = '';
const finale = 13;

for(let i = 0, j = 1; i <= finale; string_fibo += i + ' ', [i,j] = [j, i + j]);

console.log(string_fibo);
```

Можно и вовсе без предварительного объявления переменных и без ограничений практически.

```js
for(var string = '', i = 0, j = 1; i != Infinity; string += i + ' ', [i,j] = [j, i + j]);

console.log(string);
```

Если очень хочется, то можно и `console.log` включить в выражение.

```js
for(let string = '', i = 0, j = 1; i != Infinity ? true : console.log(string.trimEnd()); string += i + ' ', [i,j] = [j, i + j]);
```

А можно и все впихнуть в секцию 2 (условие работы/прекращения цикла):

```js
for(let s='',i=0,j=1;(s+=i+' ')&&([i,j]=[j,i+j])[0]!=Infinity?true:console.log(s.trimEnd()););
```

**P.S.** Надеюсь, понятно, что это порочная практика. Код пишется для людей и хороший код понятен с первого взгляда. Поэтому задание изначально неприемлемое.

Comment: Простите, люди добрые. Хотелось поразвлечься на тему Фибоначччччи и тупых условий задач. От Фибоначчи уже уши все завяли. Что с этой условностью носиться как с писаной торбой вообще не понятно...

Comment: ух, про цифры удивил, плюс за такой лаконичный пример, даже на заметку взял.